# The vanishing property of a compact operator acting on an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

The question is:

> Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space, $A \in K(H)$, and $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$. Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \langle Ae_n, e_n \rangle = 0$.

$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ is the inner product defined on $H$.

$A \in K(H)$ means $A$ is a compact operator (thus linear and continuous) mapping $H$ to itself.

There are numerous ways to define a compact operator. Suppose $X, Y$ are Banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator. The followings are equivalent:

1. $T$ is compact
2. the closure of the image of any bounded set (or just consider the unit ball in $X$) is compact (i.e. let $E$ be bounded in $X$, then $\overline{TE}$ is compact in $Y$)
3. the image of any bounded set (or just consider the unit ball in $X$) is totally bounded (i.e. $TE$ is totally bounded in $Y$ if $E$ is bounded in $X$)
4. the image of any bounded sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence in $Y$ (i.e. if $\{x_n\}$ is bounded in $X$, then $\{Tx_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence

I totally have no idea how to prove this amazing effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. As $A$ is compact, there is a finite rank operator $T$ such that $\|A-T\|\leq\varepsilon$. Then, 
$$|\langle Ae_n,e_n\rangle|\leq|\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle|+\varepsilon$$

But as $T$ has finite rank, you know that $\mathrm{Im} T\subset \mathrm{Vect}(e_1,\cdots,e_N)$ for some  $N\geq 0$. This will imply that $$\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle=0$$
as soon as $n> N$.

This shows what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks! This proof uses the fact that finite operators are dense in the space of compact operators. But our teacher didn't cover this in class.

Comment: I think this is a good exercise to prove this by your own, the idea is to use the precompacity criterion in Banach spaces (a subset is precompact iff it can be approached by a finite dimensional vector space as precisely as you want). This criterion itself is important and it is an important exercise to show it

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: The hypothesis is $\|A-T\|\leq\varepsilon$.
So, $|\langle Ae_n,e_n\rangle|\leq |\langle (A-T)e_n,e_n\rangle|+|\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle|\leq \|A-T\|\|e_n\|\|e_n\|+|\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle|\leq\varepsilon+|\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle|$, where I use the triangular inequality, Cauchy Schwarz and the definition of the subordinate norm